# vBulletin inside Laravel application

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, vbulletin

I recently finished my website's transition to Laravel and all that is left is the current forum software, **vBulletin**.

Right now, my website consists of various Blade files (all extending the main layout).

For the forum to work, I had to place all vBulletin files in a `/forum` directory inside `/public` and access them directly (having to add an exception in .htaccess file). So, by accessing them directly (by visiting `example.com/public/forum/index.php` for example), I am loosing all the Laravel functionality. But I also want to use some methods and controllers I have already defined in my Laravel site. Get the current user, his profile picture and other stuff.

Moreover, how can I use the Blade files outside of Laravel? For example, I would like to have a common header (which is already in its own header.blade.php file). How can I accomplish that instead of creating a new header.php file and have all blade syntax converted to html/php?

The question(s) above may be specific for vBulletin, but could be expanded to any application:

*How do we use an external application inside Laravel, utilising **Blade syntax** and all the **Classes / Controllers** already implemented?*

Thanks in advance,
Ilias

Comment: If you're installing a new forum with a fresh database, why not use Flarum? http://flarum.org/ it's an excellent forum package for laravel.

Comment: @Halnex, Flarum is currently in beta and not to be used in production environment. I am also already running vBulletin, that's why I am trying to 'include' it in my Laravel app.

Comment: @IliasKouroudis have you find a solution for your problem?

Comment: @FelipeUmpierre Unfortunately not. I ended up copying the contents of my blade templates to new files.
Off-topic: Sadly I am stuck with vBulletin, which is old (and not well-maintained) software, but I am really looking to leaving it and maybe go with Discourse or Flarum when it's ready.